# Использование model.predict в распознавании лиц

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, распознавание

У меня есть код на [GitHub](https://github.com/SzarekhSwift/My-Face-Recognition) с обучением модели и последующим распознаванием лица с камеры. Но есть проблема с методом `model.predict_proba`. Если запустить так, то выдает ошибку

```
'Sequential' object has no attribute 'predict_proba'
```

Пробовал менять на `model.predict`, но выдает другую ошибку

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 64, 64, 3), found shape=(None, 100, 3)
```

Мне подсказали уже, что я передаю изображение с shape `(100, 3)`, а модель ожидает shape `(64, 64, 3)`. И я не могу понять, почему так происходит.

Может быть кто-то в курсе почему так?

Answer (score 0):

В файле
load_dataset.py

Находится следующий код

```
# Считать данные обучения по указанному пути
def load_dataset(path_name):
    images,labels = read_path(path_name)    
    
    # Преобразуем все входные изображения в четырехмерный массив, размер (количество изображений * IMAGE_SIZE * IMAGE_SIZE * 3)
    # Картинка 64 * 64 пикселя, у одного пикселя 3 значения цвета (RGB)
    images = np.array(images)
    print(images.shape)    
    
    # Данные аннотации, в папке 'data' находятся все изображения лиц, все обозначены как 0, другая папка находится там же, все обозначены как 1
    labels = np.array([0 if label.endswith('Mark') else 1 for label in labels])
    #labels = np.array(labels)   
    
    return images, labels
```

Вы можете использовать этот код, чтобы преобразовать свое входное изображение в нужную форму "Картинка 64 * 64 пикселя, у одного пикселя 3 значения цвета (RGB)"

Comment: я уже пакетно изменил все изображения на 64х64, и это не дало какого-то результата. Там все равно появляется ошибка, что форма изображения неправильная. И мне не понятно, почему оно пишет именно 2 цифры, т.е. `(100, 3)`, а не `(100, 100, 3)`, причем вместо 100 всегда разные цифры.

Comment: Есть там такие строчки   train_images, valid_images, train_labels, valid_labels = train_test_split(images, labels, test_size = 0.3, random_state = random.randint(0, 100))        
        _, test_images, _, test_labels = train_test_split(images, labels, test_size = 0.5, random_state = random.randint(0, 100))